# Outdoor Water Spigot Will Not Turn

Tags: plumbing, valve, hose, spigot

I'm having an annoying issue with an outside water spigot.  I was watering the yard the other day and kinked the hose so I could put on an attachment.  Finished watering and when I went to turn off the spigot I noticed the wheel would not turn.  It doesn't turn clockwise or counterclockwise.  I turned off the water supply inside the house and tried to diagnose the issue.  I removed the wheel, the nut/washer, and attempted to turn the stem but it will not turn either.  I'm trying to determine how to fix this.  Can I simply remove the sillcock and replace that or is that attached to the pipe that goes into the house, in which case I need to replace the whole thing?  Hoping there is a quick fix before I attempt to replace the pipe and sillcock completely.  [image]

Comment: I should add that it is stuck in the on position.  So the only way to turn it off at this point is to do so at the shut off valve inside the house.

Comment: you can do a temporary fix with one of these ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=garden+hose+shutoff+valve&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: These don't last forever.  You might be better off just to remove and replace the whole thing.  These connect inside the wall, so you'll have to get at it there.  Some are screw-on and others are soldered fittings.

Comment: Maybe judicious use of lubricant and a stronger wrist will free up the valve.

Comment: What's on the other side of that brick? if it's inaccessible then one would hope that the plumber used a threaded connector. If it is threaded then it could just be difficult to turn due to hard water buildup. If this issue has you stumped then I would call in a plumber instead of making things worse; it sounds like you do not have the right tools, parts, nor knowledge to fix this when you inadvertently make the issue worse.

Comment: @Jay Here's your "quick-fix" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ken6iYx0Y1g

Comment: Have you tried to unscrew the hex bushing that holds the packing material around the valve stem? Removing that may allow you to remove the stem and replace the packing and washer. Not positive it will work but it is a simple thing to try.

Comment: Thanks all.  Shut off valve is a good temporary fix until I decide to tackle it.  It's an old house so maybe it just finally went on me.  @MonkeyZeus I think the sillcock is attached to the pipe (all one piece) which is 12 inches long.  Goes through the brick and I believe its threaded on the end...attached to an elbow under the kitchen sink that goes to the water supply.  I can get to the hex nut that attaches there so maybe I can give that a shot.

Comment: I would absolutely unscrew the hex part still visibly attached as @Gil inquires about. That is your key to just replacing the innards, rather than the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you said, "I think the sillcock is attached to the pipe (all one piece) which is 12 inches long. Goes through the brick and I believe its threaded on the end" and that sounds like that's exactly what you want!

It's a "frost proof" spigot, where the actual valve is inside the house so it doesn't freeze up on you in the winter. The 12" of empty pipe protects you from flooding.

Since you know where it connects inside, it's very likely a simple job of unscrewing it from the inside (2 wrenches - one on the elbow under the sink to hold it steady, and one on the sillcock's pipe to turn it), removing it and replacing it with a new one.

It looks like a replacement will run you in the neighborhood of $40 USD. You can probably replace it yourself in about 30 minutes if you know what you're doing, so budget 2 hours, just to be on the safe side. (My rule of thumb, even after years of working on my own house.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Yep I just got back from Home Depot to price out frost proof spigots w/ 12" pipe and it's around $45.  So I'm going to use a shutoff valve for right now and then pick up the piece this weekend when I can give myself some time.  Might be an easy job after all.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, @Jay. If you'll take a moment to take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to any and all answers that help you. Give it a few hours or even a day or two, then click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_.  That also helps others who may have the same problem find that their question has already been asked and has a good answer.

Comment: Before you go back to Home Depot, make note not only of the pipe length on the anti-siphon faucet, but also whether it's got a 1/2" or 3/4" NPT threaded male end.